# Why didn't Vincent and Jules use silencers in Pulp Fiction?

Tags: plot-explanation, pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction*, when Vincent and Jules kill Brett and the others they do not use silencers. Also Jules shouts loudly during his *Ezekiel* monologue. I find it odd because the noise surely alert the neighbors and they possibly call the cops. We know that the walls are thin because we hear television noises while they are walking on the corridor.

On the other hand Wallace's gun, that he left in Butch's apartment, had a silencer.

Why did Vincent and Jules risk getting caught by making too much noise?

Comment: Knowing there's a drug addicted group nearby, potentially even having guns etc. would you really react to hearing them screaming yet again? Gun shots are something different, but then again you don't know how often there are reports about gun shots with nothing actually happening? Of course real cops would have to check, but it's a movie after all. And who would really oppose *"the Lord [that lays his] vengeance upon you"*?

Comment: http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/11/gun-silencers-dont-make-them-anywhere-near-silent/

Comment: I got the impression Marsellus Wallace was a pretty big deal crime lord.  I doubt his hitmen are too worried about people hearing their gunshots.  I mean, they waltzed right into that apartment building, talking the whole way.  They even stood outside the apartment for a while.  Plenty of chances for neighbours to see them and connect them to the crime scene, even if they HAD used silencers on their weapons.

Comment: @Mario I would be quite unhappy if the neighbour starts shouting and shooting at 7:30 at the morning.

Comment: @Paulie_D I never heard a real gunshot in my life, but based on youtube videos silencers make a huge difference in the noise level.

Comment: @Steve-O This might be the explanation, maybe the police was in their hands. They also didn't clear any of their fingerprints so probably they knew they had nothing to worry about.

Comment: Silencers are illegal in California, and Jules and Vincent did not want to do anything illegal.

Comment: @JohnnyBones like drink a beer in an AMERICAN movie theater.

Answer (score 2):

Not everyone is willing to call the police, and in some areas of some cities, most people are highly reluctant to call the police. Some common reasons include:

- Anyone who would hear the gunfire has reason to avoid the police because of their own current or recent criminal activity
- Anyone in earshot knows who is involved in the shooting and knows if they try to get Marcellus Wallace's men arrested they will be hurt or killed in retribution
- The police in the area may have a reputation for being corrupt, meaning it could be useless at best and dangerous at worst to ever call them (a real life example would be the Rampart scandal of late 1990s LAPD - the basis for the movie *Training Day*)
- The police might be very reluctant to come to the area in question, meaning it might be useless to call them

Some of the attitudes towards the police that cause trouble in some areas are reflected in the popular culture, as in songs like "F___ The Police" and "911 Is A Joke In Your Town" (911 is the emergency services number in North America). More recently, the movie *Get Out* and the Black Lives Matter movement are examples of mistrust of law enforcement.

If I understand correctly, silencers are not convenient to use. They may affect the accuracy of the weapon and make get hot. Plus you have to buy and carry one to have it available when it's time to murder. So it may not make sense if you have no compelling need to use one.

It could also be a sign of machismo to not use one. What if Vincent started putting one on his gun? Maybe Jules would tease him for it.

Comment: Hmmm.... It would be a huge risk to assume that no one would cause the police for those reasons (or if they did, the police wouldn't respond), however though I don't know too much about guns, I have heard that in real life, silencers are not like the usual movie ones where they reduce the sound to a little "pew". There's still a loud bang it's just not as deafening.